# undefined method `valid?' for #<Class:0x94b626c>

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

Why am  getting this error? How to fix?

```
  1) User should exist
     Failure/Error: User.should be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `valid?' for #<Class:0x94b626c>
```

Test is:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  it "should exist" do
    User.should be_valid
  end 
  it "should not allow me to create a new user without required fields" do
    User.new(:email => 'bob').should_not be_valid
  end 

end
```

The second test works ok, how can I get the first one to pass? I just want it to check that the model exists

Comment: Wouldn't `valid?` be on the instance on the User class rather than the User class itself?

Comment: yes. How can I check that the class exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing a class implicitly tests that it exists. Both code samples will error out if the class doesn't exist. The first is unnecessary.

Comment: good point.  The drawback is that the failure then happens for all the test that user it rather than highlighting the fact that the model itself doesn't exist.  One option I am trying is `User.all.count.should == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `User.should be_valid` with `User.new.should be_valid` in the first test. RSpec is calling `valid?` on the User class instead of an instance of it.